# How to detect FileReader load end?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following model with a file reading function. However, the reading is done after the next piece of code. Why and how can I get it to return the read content of the file?

```
   TreeContainer = Backbone.Model.extend({
                elementCount: 0,
                file: '',
                object: {jj: "kk"},
                type: "input",
                parent: d3.select("#canvas"),
                initialize: function () {
                    var result = this.readFile();
                    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                        console.log(i); //this is resulted before the readFile content
                    }

                },
                readFile: function () {
                    var model = this;
                    // display text
                    if (this.get('file').name.endsWith(".json") || this.get('file').type === "application/json") {

                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            //parseJSON
                            var text = e.target.result;
                            var data = JSON.parse(text);
                            model.set('object', data);
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(this.get('file'));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fallen for the [async for loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

You can only loop over all files after you have read all the content
Here is a example using [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader)

```
initialize: function(){
    this.readFile().then(arr => {
        for (let json of arr) {
            console.log(json) //this is resulted before the readFile content
        }
    })
},
readFile: function() {
    function isJSON(file) { 
        return file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith('.json') ||
        file.type === 'application/json'
    }

    return Promise.all(
        Array.from(input.files)
        .filter(isJSON)
        .map(file => file.json())
    )
}
```

Alternetive is to wrap FileReader in a Promise

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var text = e.target.result
        var data = JSON.parse(text)
        model.set('object', data)
        resolve(data)
    }
})
```

or send in a callback

```
initialize: function(){
    this.readFile(json => {
        json
    })
},
readFile: function(resolve) {
    resolve(data)
}
```